# Log in into google not using selenium

Tags: javascript, python

It seems that google patched logging into their services via entering links to log in into google on other sites. I came up with an idea, to log in via importing profile from the native chrome browser. The thing is, that I need to log in to google's services there as well. I was thinking about writing a JS code to do so, but the problem is that I need to somehow export the profile's folder after login as well. It needs to be fully automated, but from what I have read I can not execute copying directory directly from the browser. So my question is, how can I copy and paste the folder within the same computer using JS? Or how can I execute JS code via Python, **not using selenium but native chrome browser**?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a small api with flask and run through render_template the static files of js, then with js put it in the body and from there collect the answer

### Python Script

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def getCode():
    print("index.html")
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(port=5000)
```

### HTML Body

```
<body>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='runtime.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
```

Now you must save the html in a folder called template and the js in a folder called static

1. Tree:

   - static

     - runtime.js
   - template

     - index.html
   - main.py